# Find a map in list of map java stream

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I am iterating through a List of Hashmap to find the required HashMap object using the following code.

```
public static Map<String, String> extractMap(List<Map<String, String>> mapList, String currentIp) {
    for (Map<String, String> asd : mapList) {
        if (asd.get("ip").equals(currentIp)) {
            return asd;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I was thinking about using Java 8 stream. This is the code I used to display the required object.

```
public static void displayRequiredMapFromList(List<Map<String, String>> mapList, String currentIp) {
    mapList.stream().filter(e -> e.get("ip").equals(currentIp)).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I couldn't get the required Map from the stream using following code

```
public static Map<String, String> extractMapByStream(List<Map<String, String>> mapList, String currentIp) {
    return mapList.stream().filter(e -> e.get("ip").equals(currentIp))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
}
```

This causes syntax error *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map to Map*. What do I have to put here to get Map?

Comment: mapList.stream().filter(e -> e.get("ip").equals(currentIp)).findFirst() ... Note that this returns an Optional<Map ...>

Comment: Consider defining classes rather than nested collections. It gets hard to understand what a `List<Map<Set<String>, Map<Integer, List<HttpClient>>>>` is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will will work, the other examples without `orElse()` don't compile (at least they don't in my IDE).

```
mapList.stream()
    .filter(asd -> asd.get("ip").equals(currentIp))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

The only thing I would add as a suggestion is to return `Collections.emptyMap()`, this will save a null check in the calling code.

To get the code to compile without `orElse` you need to change the method signature to:

```
public static Optional<Map<String, String>> extractMap(List<Map<String, String>> mapList, String currentIp)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to `.collect` anything. You want to find the first map that matches the predicate.

So you should use `.findFirst()` instead of `.collect()`.

`toMap()` is for building a `Map` from the elements in the stream.

But you don't want to do that, each element is already a `Map`.

Comment: if order is not needed, one might also use `findAny()`

Comment: I have accepted @Andrew's answer only because it completely translated my for loop method to stream with else *null* that is. Thank you.

Comment: @MuneebMirza That's fine. :) I recommend that you `return` the  `Optional<Map<String,String>>` instead of `.orElse(null)`. What are you doing with the `null` that is returned anyway?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström so you are saying that I should instead return at `findFirst()`? Yes i think this makes more sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

User this

```
    public static Map<String, String> extractMapByStream(List<Map<String, String>> mapList, String currentIp) {
        return mapList.stream().filter(e -> e.get("ip").equals(currentIp))
            .findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: compiler error: `Type Optional<Map<String, String>> is not assignable to type Map<String, String>`

Comment: thats because findFirst() returns Optional and we have to call get() on it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare No, you don't blindly call `.get()` on an `Optional` if you're not sure that it's non-empty. That defeats the whole purpose of `Optional`.